# Multiquery failing on SQL array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$postsret_query = mysqli_fetch_array($db->query("SELECT posts.id,comments.id FROM posts,comments ORDER BY timestamp_created LIMIT 10"));
echo $postsret_query['posts.id'];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($postsret_query)){  }
```

It gives me:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in G:\PHP\DEVELOPMENT\index.php on line 101
```

Then, how could I solve it? I'm using Mysqli and I want to do a query which gets the last posts (from posts) and the last comments (from comments) and give it on the array for show 10 lasts of that as 1 while.
Anyone knows the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns an array representing the results of a particular row.  As the error suggests, the parameter passed to it needs to be a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) resource.

The first call to mysql_fetch_array in your example works because mysqli_result is the return type from the [query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) method.

However, once you hit the while loop, you're now passing in that associative array instead of a mysqli_result resource.

Try refactoring the code like this:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT p.id  AS `posts.id` , c.id  AS `comments.id` FROM posts JOIN comments ON c.post_id = c.id ORDER BY p.timestamp_created DESC LIMIT 10");

if ($result === false) {
    echo mysqli_error($db);
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            echo $row['posts.id'];
    }
}
```

One additional thing I would point out.  mysqli has two binding types -- object orientated and procedural.  You seem to be mixing and matching both styles.  You should settle on one.

The OO version would look more like:

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$result = $db->query("SELECT p.id  AS `posts.id` , c.id  AS `comments.id` FROM posts JOIN comments ON c.post_id = c.id ORDER BY p.timestamp_created DESC LIMIT 10");

if ($result === false) {
    echo $db->error;
} else {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
            echo $row['posts.id'];
    }
}
```

whereas the procedural version would look like:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT p.id  AS `posts.id` , c.id  AS `comments.id` FROM posts JOIN comments ON c.post_id = c.id ORDER BY p.timestamp_created DESC LIMIT 10");

if ($result === false) {
    echo mysqli_error($db);
} else {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
            echo $row['posts.id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that the query call is failing for some reason.  Check if $result === false and if it does, then echo out the result of mysqli_error($db) or $db->error if you are using procedural or OO style respectively.

Comment: @Andrei Garcia: The query is failing, and returning FALSE (a boolean) rather than a resultset. You need to test the return from query, and if it's FALSE, don't try to fetch from it. The query in this answer (copied from the question) doesn't return a column named `posts.id`. And it has other problems as well. More PHP code isn't going to fix the query. See my answer. I think keelerm (reasonably) assumed that you had a query that worked.

Comment: I updated my code sample to reflect the improved query spencer posted in the other answer.  Hopefully this helps address your issue.

Comment: @keelerm: you might also want to show a `if(!$result) { echo "error"; } else`. My query was just a guess, I'm not sure what result OP wants to return; I just know the OP SQL statement isn't going to return what OP wants or expects.

Comment: Good idea.  Updated to add some rudimentary error handling.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes about the query itself: the query is doing a cross join between posts and comments, columns in the select list are qualified, but the reference to the column `timestamp_created` in the `order by` clause isn't qualified.

The query is using old-school comma syntax for join operations.  It's time to ditch that, and use the `JOIN` keyword.

Also, the columns returned in the resultset will both have `id` as the column name. The qualifier on the column reference isn't returned.  If you want to return the column named as `posts.id`, you'd need to assign an alias to the expression in the `select` list.

I suspect that you don't want a Cartesian product (cross join operation.) I suspect you want to match the `comment` with the `post`.

```
  SELECT p.id  AS `posts.id`
       , c.id  AS `comments.id` 
    FROM posts
    JOIN comments
      ON c.post_id = c.id
   ORDER BY p.timestamp_created DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

We're just guessing at what resultset you want to return.

But your query is definitely not going to return a column named `posts.id`.

---

keleem just now posted an answer about the code, so no need to repeat that here.

---

If you want to return the id from the 10 latest posts, and the id from the 10 latest comments, you don't need a join operation at all.

If the dataypes of the `id` columns from `posts` and `comments` is compatible, you could do something like:

```
  ( -- latest 10 posts 
    SELECT 'post' AS type
         , p.id
      FROM posts p
     ORDER BY p.timestamp_created DESC
     LIMIT 10
  )
  UNION ALL
  ( -- latest 10 comments 
    SELECT 'comment'
         , c.id
      FROM comments c
     ORDER BY c.timestamp_created DESC
     LIMIT 10
  )
```

If you want to guarantee an ordering of the entire result, you'd need to return the `timestamp_created` as a column, and specify an ORDER BY on that. For example:

```
SELECT v.type
     , v.id
  FROM (
         ( -- latest 10 posts 
           SELECT 'post' AS type
                , p.id
                , c.timestamp_created
             FROM posts p
            ORDER BY p.timestamp_created DESC
            LIMIT 10
         )
         UNION ALL
         ( -- latest 10 comments 
           SELECT 'comment'
                , c.id
                , c.timestamp_created
             FROM comments c
            ORDER BY c.timestamp_created DESC
            LIMIT 10
         )
       ) v
 ORDER BY v.timestamp_created DESC
```

Comment: im too tard, could u combine it with my code? ty m8!

Comment: @AndreiGarcia: Maybe you should write two separate queries. `SELECT id FROM posts ORDER BY timestamp_created DESC LIMIT 10`, and a similar from `comments. If you want to return a more complicated result, start with some sample data, and a specification (like an example) of what you want returned. From that, you can develop a SQL statement. And test the SQL statement outside of the code, from another client.

Comment: @AndreiGarcía Lol, are you going to be paying him to develop a solution for you? If not I don't think you should be asking anyone to write your code for you.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7azonq Need the last helpy helpy. Just did that, it works (thank u :P), but how can i call the posts ID/Name of the post? because i juust called title which is at posts but bot at comments, and if i put comments.id / posts.title it gives me an error. ty and sry for being that creepy D: -> IT JUST RETRIEVES ME THE ID

Comment: You're "too tard" ? As in exhausted (tired)? Or as in stupid (r'tard)? Or both?

Comment: here is 5 am and im programming for 17 hours so both :p

Comment: @AndreiGarcía: I feel for you buddy. I've been there and done that too. It's good to take a break! But keep slugging, we are rooting for you, dude. It's hard, but it's not rocket surgery.